# More idiomatic (monadic?) way to express this Scala

Tags: scala, monads

I have several blocks of code that follow this pattern:

```
// Dummy function defs.
def result(i : Int, d : Double, b : Boolean) = {
    if (b) d else i
}

def fA(s : String) = {7}
def fB(s : String, i : Int) = {1.0}
def fC(s : String, i : Int, d : Double) = {true}

// Actual code.
def test(s : String) : Double = {
    try {
        val a = fA(s) 
        try {
            val b = fB(s, a)
            try {
                val c = fC(s, a, b)
                result(a, b, c)
            } catch {
                case _ => result(a, b, false)
            }

        } catch {
            case _ => result(a, 0.0, false)
        }
    } catch {
        case _ => result(0, 0.0, false)
    }
}
```

Where a, b, & c are calculated in turn by the corresponding functions and then the values are passed to the result function. If at any stage an exception occurs then a default value is used in place of the remaining variables.

Is there a more idiomatic way to express this code. It reminds me of Monads in that it's a series of chained computations which bail out immediately if any computation fails.

Comment: Which functions can fail? `result` and/or `fA .. fC`?

Comment: @Nicolas I think fA, fB, and fC. They are noted as dummy functions. In reality they would possibly throw some exception.

Comment: Yes, should have been more clear, but as Brian says, fA, fB, & fC can throw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These types of problems are just what `Try` aims to solve a bit more monadically (than nested `try/catch` blocks).

`Try` represents a computation that may either result in an exception, or return a successfully computed value. It has two subclasses for these-- `Success` and `Failure`.

Very funny that this question popped up when it did-- a few days ago, I finished up some additions and refactoring to `scala.util.Try`, for the 2.10 release and this SO question helps to illustrate an important use-case for a combinator that we eventually decided to include; `transform`.

(As of writing this, `transform` is currently in the [nightly](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala) and will be in Scala from 2.10-M5 onward, due out today or tomorrow. More info about `Try` and usage examples can be found in the [nightly docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try))

With `transform` (by nesting them), this can be implemented using `Try`s as follows:

```
def test(s: String): Double = {
  Try(fA(s)).transform(
    ea => Success(result(0, 0.0, false)), a => Try(fB(s, a)).transform(
      eb => Success(result(a, 0.0, false)), b => Try(fC(s, a, b)).transform(
        ec => Success(result(a, b, false)), c => Try(result(a, b, c))
      )
    )
  ).get
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I look forward to trying it in Scala 2.10

Comment: Can't you use `Try(fA(s)).fold(_ => result(0, 0.0, false), a => ...)`. It seems it would spare the wrapping into `Success` as well as the final `get`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can use a for comprehension on a Try, since flatMap is defined.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure you can use monads as at each step you have two alternatives (exception or result) and to be faithful to your original code, on exception you don't want to be calling the `fB` or `fC` functions.

I was not able to elegantly remove the duplication of default values so I left it as I think it's clearer. Here is my non-monadic version based on `either.fold` and `control.Exception`:

```
def test(s : String) = {
  import util.control.Exception._
  val args = 
    allCatch.either(fA(s)).fold(err => (0, 0.0, false), a => 
      allCatch.either(fB(s, a)).fold(err => (a, 0.0, false), b =>
        allCatch.either(fC(s, a, b)).fold(err => (a, b, false), c =>
          (a, b, c))))
  (result _).tupled(args)
}
```

Comment: You could declare val default = (0, 0.0, false) and then use default.copy( _1 = a) or (a, b, default._3), but I'm not sure if either solution is a real enhancement. Well, at least modifying defaults could be done at only one place.

Answer (score 4):

I changed the example to use monads:

```
def fA(s: String) = Some(7)
def fB(i: Option[Int]) = Some(1.0)
def fC(d: Option[Double]) = true // might be false as well

def result(i: Int, d: Double, b: Boolean) = {
  if (b) d else i
}

def test(s: String) = result(fA(s).getOrElse(0), fB(fA(s)).getOrElse(0.0), fC(fB(fA(s))))
```

Note: The for-comprehension is interpreted as chained `flatMap`. So the type of `res` is `Option[(Int, Double, Boolean)]`. Therefore there is no need to write `map` or `flatMap` by yourself. The compiler does the work for you. :)

**Edit**

I edited my code to make it fit to all possibilitys. I will improve it, if I find a better way. Thank you for all your comments.

Comment: That solution miss the fact that fA, fB, fC are able to throw exception in the real case, else surronding them with try/catch is of no use in the question. So that answer seems to miss the what was the user problem, which I understand as "how do I chain perhaps failing computation, given them default value in case of failure"

Comment: This solution is wrong. If `fA` succeeds but `fB` fails, `a` should be equal to result of `fA` and `b = 0.0` and `c = false`. With your code, any failure leads to `result(0, 0.0, false)`.

Comment: This looks promising, but as others point out, it doesn't appear to handle the case where say fA succeeds, but fB fails so we call result(a, 0, false)

Comment: I appreciate your comments. Of course i know the real code might fail, but this is to handle in the function by returning None. I did not add this behaviour because I only wanted to outline, how the example might be changed to use monads. If you enter this code into the REPL, you wold see that the return types of the functions are Some[T] and not Option[T]. This was my first idea to improve the code. So please forgive me if I did not adapt all aspects of the original example.

Comment: @T.Grottker, you're missing the point. I understood that you changed `f`s to return an `Option`. That's indeed a good idea. But this code does not behave as expected. When `fA` returns `Some(3)` and `fB` and `fC` return `None`, then `result` should be called with `(3, 0.0, false)`. Your code calls it with `(0, 0.0, false)`. That's what I meant when I said that with your code any failure directly leads to `result(0, 0.0, false)` which is not the expected behavior.

Comment: @missingfaktor Thank you, I understood your point. Yes that happens because of the flatMap. It will just chain if the answer is not None. You are right. This is not as expected. I will improve my code.

Comment: As your answer currently stands you're calling fA 3 times and fB twice.

Answer (score 3):

By defining those utility functions

```
implicit def eitherOps[E, A](v: Either[E, A]) = new {
  def map[B](f: A => B) = v match {
    case Left(e)  => Left(e)
    case Right(a) => Right(f(a))    
  }

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Either[E, B]) = v match {
    case Left(e)  => Left(e)
    case Right(a) => f(a)
  }

  def or(a: A) = v match {
    case Left(_) => Right(a)
    case x       => x          
  }
}

def secure[A, B](f: A => B) = new {
  def run(a: A): Either[Trowable, B]  = try {
    Right(f(a))
  } catch {
    case e => Left(e)
  }
}
```

and simplifying yours

```
def fA(s : String) = 7
def fB(i : Int) = 1.0
def fC(d : Double) = true
```

We'll have:

```
def test(s: String): Either[Throwable, Double] =  for {
  a <- secure(fA).run(s).or(0)
  b <- secure(fB).run(a).or(0.0)
  c <- secure(fC).run(b).or(false)
} yield result(a, b, c)
```

**Edit**

Here's an executable but sadly, more verbose code snippet

```
object Example {
  trait EitherOps[E, A] {
    def self: Either[E, A]

    def map[B](f: A => B) = self match {
      case Left(e)  => Left(e)
      case Right(a) => Right(f(a))    
    }

    def flatMap[B](f: A => Either[E, B]) = self match {
      case Left(e)  => Left(e)
      case Right(a) => f(a)
    }

    def or(a: A) = self match {
      case Left(_) => Right(a)
      case x       => x          
    }
  }

  trait SecuredFunction[A, B] {
    def self: A => B

    def secured(a: A): Either[Throwable, B]  = try {
      Right(self(a))
    } catch {
      case e => Left(e)
    }
  }

  implicit def eitherOps[E, A](v: Either[E, A]) = new EitherOps[E, A] {
    def self = v
  }

  implicit def opsToEither[E, A](v: EitherOps[E, A]) = v.self

  implicit def secure[A, B](f: A => B) = new SecuredFunction[A, B]{
    def self = f
  }

  def fA(s : String) = 7
  def fB(i : Int) = 1.0
  def fC(d : Double) = true

  def result(i : Int, d : Double, b : Boolean) = {
    if (b) d else i
  }

  def test(s: String): Either[Throwable, Double] =  for {
    a <- (fA _).secured(s) or 0
    b <- (fB _).secured(a) or 0.0
    c <- (fC _).secured(b) or false
  } yield result(a, b, c)
}
```

Comment: As I said in the question, the definitions provided for fA, fB & fC are just dummy defs, to allow the code to compile. Optimising them as you have done misses the point.

Comment: There is no optimization. You don't need to carry around other computed values since I provided default value if computation failed and they're in scope through the monadic computation. Unless you've already run the code, I think you missed the point of my post

Comment: Yo your post is good, (besides it doesn't compile OOTB) . We need to coomunicate the difference with this approach. The problem is indeed the sequential thinking, this is in my opinion the root of jons alidation problem. And that is what apparently got lost in all answers here. The point is jon you have to encode possible failure within the result type of your methods otherwise you won't get 'Monadic' benefits.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll come up with a compilable version. I've written the code "by hand" :).

Comment: Apologies for my previous comment - for some reason I thought your solution required changes to the f[A-C] functions.

Answer (score 2):

I generally solve most try-catch problems using a combination of `map + recover` or `flatMap + recoverWith`.

**In general, I prefer chaining over nesting**

There are many ways to skin a cat. Here are 3:

I presume fA, fB and fC are contrived examples of more complex logic. If they are indeed as noddy as the example then option 3 is simplest.

1. This one is my preferred way. Readability here is a lot better than nested flatMaps

```
def test(s: String): Double =
  (for {
    a <- Try(fA(s)).recover { case _ => 0 }
    b <- Try(fB(s, a)) recover { case _ => 0.0 }
    c <- Try(result(a, b, fC(s, a, b))) recover { case _ => result(a, b, false) }
  } yield c).get
```

2. This one is the same as the previous one after de-sugaring the for-expressions into flatMaps although it looks more nested than chained.

```
def test(s: String): Double =
  Try(fA(s)).recover { case _ => 0 }
    .flatMap(a =>
      (Try(fB(s, a)) recover { case _ => 0.0 })
        .flatMap(b =>
          Try(result(a, b, fC(s, a, b))) 
            recover { case _ => result(a, b, false) }
        )
    ).get
```

Readability is not great because args into flatMap are written as anonymous functions. If I rewrite this without using anon functions then I have:

```
def test(s: String): Double = {
  val evalA = Try(fA(s)).recover { case _ => 0 }
  val evalB: Int => Try[Double] = a => 
    Try(fB(s, a)) recover { case _ => 0.0 }
  val evalC: (Int, Double) => Try[Double] = (a,b) =>
    Try(result(a, b, fC(s, a, b))) recover { case _ => result(a, b, false) }

  evalA.flatMap(a =>
    evalB(a).flatMap(b =>
      evalC(a, b))
  ).get
}
```

3. You could use `getOrElse()` if no other side-effects required.

```
def test(s: String) = {
  val evalA = Try(fA(s)).getOrElse(0)
  val evalB = Try(fB(s, evalA)).getOrElse(0.0)
  val evalC = Try(fC(s, evalA, evalB)).getOrElse(false)

  result(evalA, evalB, evalC)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `catching` idiom as follows:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._

def test(s : String) : Double = result(
  catching(classOf[Exception]).opt( fA(s) ).getOrElse(0),
  catching(classOf[Exception]).opt( fB(s, a) ).getOrElse(0.0),
  catching(classOf[Exception]).opt( fC(s, a, b) ).getOrElse(false)
)
```

However, similarly to other solutions, this does make a slight executional change in that `fB` and `fC` will always be evaluated, whereas your original code only evaluates them if the prior calls succeeded.

Comment: Nice, but I don't want to call fB etc if a prior function throws as they're costly to call.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to make it more functional.
Not sure if this solution is clearer than yours, but I think it shoud fit better if you'll have more computation steps.

```
def result(i : Int, d : Double, b : Boolean) = {
    if (b) d else i
}

def fA(s : String) = {7}
def fB(s : String, i : Int) = {1.0}
def fC(s : String, i : Int, d : Double) = {true}

type Data = (Int, Double, Boolean)
def test(s : String) : Double = {
  val steps = Seq[Data => Data](
    {case (_, b, c) => (fA(s), b, c)},
    {case (a, _, c) => (a, fB(s, a), c)},
    {case (a, b, _) => (a, b, fC(s, a, b))}
  )
  val defaults: Either[Data, Data] = Right((0, 0.0, false))
  val resultData = steps.foldLeft { defaults } { (eith, func) =>
    eith match {
      case left: Left[_,_] => left
      case Right(data) => try {
        Right(func(data))
      } catch {
        case _ => Left(data)
      }
    }
  } fold (identity, identity)
  (result _) tupled (resultData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers seem to miss the fact that you want default result at each level. 
No need to be fancy with for expression here, you just need an helper function:

```
def optTry[T]( f: => T) : Option[T] = try { Some(f) } catch { case e:Exception => None }
```

OK, `optTry` is a bad name (I'm not good at that game), but then, you can just:

```
def test(s : String) : Double = {
  val a = optTry(fA(s)) getOrElse 0
  val b = optTry(fB(s,a)) getOrElse 0.0
  val c = optTry(fC(s,a,b)) getOrElse false

  result(a,b,c)
}
```

Notice that Scala 2.10 will have a `Try` data structure that basically does the same thing with a pimped `Either` in place of `Option`, see: http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try

Also notice that `try { ... } catch { case _ => ... }` is a bad idea, you certainly don't want to catch some system Exception like OutOfMemory and the like.

EDIT: also, see Scalaz `Validation` data structure for a world of awe for all that kind of problems. See: http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleValidation.scala.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution also calls all 3 functions even if one of them throws. I need to avoid doing this.

Comment: You don't need the optTry function. `getOrElse` function is available on `Try`; you don't need to convert it to an `Option`
When you do want to convert a Try to Option, you can simply call the `toOption` on it. e.g. `Try(expr).toOption`